# dynamically add buttons?

Tags: android

i want to add some buttons dynamically at some positions,can anyone suggest a sample code for this??

Comment: Oh my friend! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Where you want to add button dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

That's how you can add a button to a group at runtime:

```
final ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.some_group);
final Button button = new Button(context);
button.setText("Some text");
group.addView(button,
    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setContentView(R.layout.medplan_index);
```

> Take Orientation of linear Layout vertical.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);   

Button btn = new Button (this);
btn.setText("button name");
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
linearLayout.addView(btn);
```